# Where's Submit button to register .ETH domain?

Tags: addresses, address.transfer

When I attempt to register a .ETH domain at https://registrar.ens.domains, there is no button for me to submit my request. Right below the message "I understand how the process works and my risks and responsibilities involved", there is a button that reads "LOADING DICTIONARY", but this button is not highlighted in order for me to click it for domain submission.

1. Am I on the correct website to purchase an ETH domain?
2. Is there another way to submit my auction request?
3. Or what can be done to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[myetherwallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#ens) has a good interface for interacting with ENS; it might be worth giving that a go.

[image]

https://registrar.ens.domains is the correct, official website, but it also has a few bugs.